# Advice for clustering a tricky data set

Tags: clustering, scikit-learn

I have a  set of data with about 15,000 vectors which fall into three classes all with the same number of vectors.  Some of the data is categorical and some numerical so I am using `DictVectorizer` to convert it to a sparse matrix.  This performs a one-hot encoding of the categorical data. Here are the key facts and my problem.

- If I build a [Random Forest](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) I get very good accuracy for classification. One-versus-rest gives me over 0.95 for the AUC for example. However Logistic Regression, for example, does not give a good result at all (AUC of around 0.55). On the other hand a large decision tree with 1,000 leaves also gives an AUC of around 0.9. This is mean AUC using cross-validation.
- I can't find an unsupervised way to cluster the data however which gives a good result at all. For example, I tried [KMeans](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) but the clusters it finds are not well separated.

The fact that the decision tree works well makes me suspect that the data has a very particular form which makes KMeans (with the default settings at least) unsuitable.  I think I need maybe to find a clustering method that effectively builds a decision tree for each cluster.

> What can I try that might work for clustering such data?

This is mostly an experiment at the moment so I can learn  more about clustering, which is new to me. If there is anything about the data that would be helpful to know, please ask.

Comment: What dimensionality is the data? The first thing you should do is plot it. There are also methods for using random forests for clustering, though I don't think scikit-learn has them built in.

Comment: @Dougal After conversion to numerical data it is 15,000 by ~300.  I did try PCA and then plotting it in 2d but it wasn't hugely informative.  I would be very interested  in a random  forest based clustering method if there is any code for that available.

Comment: Maybe you should clarify your motivation for wanting to cluster the data. For instance, you seem to have built a pretty good classifier using random forests so what is your motivation for employing those unsupervised learning approaches--are you trying to reduce the size of your data first?

Comment: Also, remember that plotting your data in two dimensions will only be revealing if a substantial amount of information can be captured by the first two principal components (and cramming 300 dimensions of info into the plane will probably not leave you with anything too fruitful)...

Comment: @SteveS My motivation is partly just to understand the methods and data better. However I also have a lot of unlabelled data from a similar source and I am hoping to be able to infer new classes within that once I have a method that works on the labelled part. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: **Why** do you want to cluster a *labeled* data set? Also, k-means assumes *continuous* variables. It is *not* surprising that it doesn't work well with one-hot encoded data. **Do *not* expect clusters to agree with your classes*. Clustering is of interest to find *new* structure to *manually* analyze afterwards. For a classification problem, k-means will get you nowhere.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I am both trying to understand my data and the methods.  If k means is the wrong tool, do you have suggestions for what to use for mixed categorical and numerical data?  Re: why classify labelled data, I am also hoping that I can use what I learn from this stage to do a sensible clustering of my unlabelled data later on.

Comment: Search for "clustering mixed" on this website and stats.SE. Plenty of questions, plenty of answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should focus on dimensionality reduction. The following two facts give me that intution:

1. It is not unusual that KMeans fails in such a high dimensional
   space, as the ["distance between any two points in a given (high
   dimensional) dataset
   converges"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_high-dimensional_data).
2. PCA can also fail if the principal axes of the classes are parallel
   to each other ("ADIDAS problem"). In this case Linear discriminant
   analysis (LDA) for dimensionality reduction could help. You could
   also give Local Linear Embedding/Laplacian Eigenmaps a try - these are dimensionality  reduction techniques that want to preserve the structure of the high dimensional dataset in the lower dimensions.

Unfortunately I haven't used scikit yet, so I don't know which techniques are implemented there...

Comment: Thank you. LDA and LLE are both available in scikit learn (see eg http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.LocallyLinearEmbedding.html). I will try them out. However I worry the partly categorical nature of the original data may be part of what makes clustering hard and also what makes decision trees work well.

Comment: I found another thread which supports your worries about clustering with categorical data:    http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22/k-means-clustering-for-mixed-numeric-and-categorical-data